# Renaming column names to blank in SELECT

Tags: sql-server-2008, alias

How to rename the column names to blank as in I don't want the column names to be displayed in the output :). I do not want a temporary change or a html/xml formatting. May be it is a very basic question but I am not able to find a good answer so far.

Comment: I can't get my head around why this would ever become a requirement - you *should* be referencing columns by name rather than ordinal position. And what's the `alert` tag about?

Comment: In the output from what?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I dont want any column names...it is a requirement...and who is talking abt any ordinal position here?

Comment: @Sharmi. Tables don't output anything. Oojahs output Tables!

Comment: @TonyHopkinson Ofcourse tables dont output anything but output can be derived from the tables through some queries. :)

Comment: Exactly. So which mechanism you use to output the table defines the options you have for configuring that output. ie giving your columns a "blank" name versus, simply not outputing the headings.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson It is about giving blank alias to the columns while displaying the SELECT query results, to be precise. :)

Comment: @TonyHopkinson ....Only if that was so easy, you still didnt get it or something...I already dont want temporary changes... i will be using this output to send a mail. Seems like you are one.. :)

Comment: @TonyHopkinson ohh i have to tell you u dont understand first the question and secondly u were the one who gave some suggestions to mention you so. :) and anyways i already got the perfect answer here so doesnt matter anyways now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a single space as the alias name. Aliases defined as "" or [] are not allowed.

```
SELECT Column1 AS [ ]
```

Comment: That was great :) exactly my requirement. That solved it like awesome.

Answer (score 1):

Should be as simple as (notice the space between the quotes):

```
Select 'ColumnName' as ' ' From TableName
```

Comment: Hey i tried that already , got this error: { An object or column name is missing or empty. For SELECT INTO statements, verify each column has a name. For other statements, look for empty alias names. Aliases defined as "" or [] are not allowed. Change the alias to a valid name. }

Comment: I've edited this post to avoid the error by adding a space between the quotes.